# Referring to a CMAKE variable from code

Tags: c++, cmake

I am using `CMAKE 3.4.3` on Windows and what I am trying to do is set a path in CMAKE and try to refer to that in my C++ file.

What I tried was as follows:

**In CMakeLists.txt file**

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DNV12_2_ARGB_PTX_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ptx")
```

Now, I try and refer to it from my C++ file as follows:

```
#ifdef NV12_2_ARGB_PTX_DIR
    #define PTX_DIR D_NV12_2_ARGB_PTX_DIR
#endif
```

And when I try to refer to it as:

```
std::cout << PTX_DIR << std::endl;
```

I get the error:

```
'C:/Users/Luca/project/src/lib/ptx': No such file or directory
```

Also, Visual studio intellisense complains:

```
IntelliSense: identifier "PTX_DIR" is undefined
```

Not sure why it wants to open a file with this variable...

Comment: Does the path `C:/Users/Luca/project/src/lib/ptx` exist on your machine? By the way, you may consider [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) for such tasks

Comment: The path exists but why does this need to be a valid path is what I do not understand? It is a variable which could have any arbitrary value. I am not trying any file operations on this yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is with your use of `add_definitions`. You're effectively passing the value of `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ptx` as an additinal argument on the compiler's command line, which the compiler probably interprets as a source file it should compile. Check the full command line invoked to be sure.

You probably intended this:

```
add_definitions(-DNV12_2_ARGB_PTX_DIR="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ptx")
```

Note that you may have to play around with escaping the quotation marks to get them all the way down to C++. Alternatively, you could use [`configure_file()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html).

Comment: Ah yes! That worked. I was playing around with `add_definitions` and `SET` commands and the equal sign got lost somewhere in the middle!

Comment: Wow, 8 upvotes within 9 hours. Obviously a great answer. And a great question, 7 people like a question about a typo.

Comment: @usr1234567 Once CMake offers a static syntax & best-practice checker, extensive introductory and explanatory non-reference documentation, and once its outputs become more easily accessible than build settings scattered across many buildsystem files, typo questions will lose their value. Until then, CMake is a tool with great use but poor usability, where "typos" and their consequences can be difficult to spot or understand, making such questions valid. Not to mention the fact that this is not really a typo, more of a misunderstanding of `add_definitions()`.

Comment: @Angew While your statement is true, it is very uncommon for a [cmake] question or answer to get so many upvotes in such a short time.